# Appending Textbox.text stops autocomplete in VB .Net VS 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, autocomplete

I have a textbox which has an autocomplete selection populated with a database query (names of individuals). I have created a keyboard using buttons as this will be a touch screen application (without using the system on-screen keyboard of Windows).

When I change or append the textbox.text value programatically (in response to my "keyboard" buttons being pressed) the autocomplete doesn't work. However using my physical keyboard it does.

How can I make the textbox start to autocomplete when the .text value is changed?

Comment: You could try using `SendKeys.Send` to simulate keyboard input.  If you think about it, it makes perfect sense that autocomplete suggestions would not be made based on changes in code.  They would generally have nothing to do with the user.

Comment: That's exactly how I've ended up doing it. Thanks for the suggestion though.